# HANK model lecture notes + code

Tags: macroeconomics, heterogeneity, simultaneous-equation-model

Can someone recommand me good lecture notes to understand macroeconomic heterogenous agent models such as HANK models (not TANK models, I know how them). Also if you know where I could find some codes that develop macro heterogeneous models that would be great.

Thnk you.